# Setting innodb_buffer_pool_size in for Mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-administration

We have a dedicated DB box with with 8 GB of RAM and running Redhat linux 64 bit OS. Our MySQL Data + Index size almost 7.8 GB. About setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, I have read 2 suggestions

- Set it to 80% of RAM available on a dedicated DB server.
- Set at-least 10% above the size of Data + Indexes.

We cannot satisfy the second condition in my case. So will it have negative effect on Database performance?

Will having `innodb_buffer_pool_size` of like 6GB affect the performance?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to answer such an general question.

It depends on so many things, no one can anticipate. Just test it and see if you have enough performance. If you don't - you can revise your indexes, clean up some data or add RAM to the server.